# Pyspark - How can I efficiently, repeatedly search through the same dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, algorithm, numpy, pyspark

I'm trying to link transactions together in a dataframe by creating a grouping column. A sample of my dataset is shown below.

| TransactionID | Amount | Barcode | TransactionId_From | TransactionId_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 55.00 | 10001 | 120 | 133 |
| 133 | 55.00 | 10001 | 120 | 133 |
| 133 | 31.00 | 10008 | 133 | NULL |
| 135 | 20.00 | 10022 | 135 | 140 |
| 10 | 20.00 | 10022 | 135 | 140 |
| 140 | 8.00 | 10056 | 140 | 149 |
| 140 | 17.00 | 10067 | 149 | NULL |
| 149 | 8.00 | 10056 | 140 | 149 |
| 151 | 5.00 | 10056 | 151 | NULL |

My goal is to group transactions which can be linked by a barcode or series of barcodes, for the above dataset the expected output would be:

| TransactionID | Amount | Barcode | TransactionId_From | TransactionId_To | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 55.00 | 10001 | 120 | 133 | 1 |
| 133 | 55.00 | 10001 | 120 | 133 | 1 |
| 133 | 31.00 | 10008 | 133 | NULL | 1 |
| 135 | 20.00 | 10022 | 135 | 140 | 2 |
| 140 | 20.00 | 10022 | 135 | 140 | 2 |
| 140 | 8.00 | 10056 | 140 | 149 | 2 |
| 149 | 8.00 | 10056 | 140 | 149 | 2 |
| 151 | 5.00 | 10058 | 151 | NULL | 3 |

Group 1 is formed by barcode 10001 linking transactions 120 and 133.
Group 2 is formed by barcodes 10022 linking transactions 135 and 140, and barcode 10056 linking transactions 140 and 149.

The number of transactions in groups is variable, usually ranging from 1-100. There are around ~180,000 barcodes and around 250,000 transactions in my dataset.

I've attempted this problem however my implementation is too slow. I suspect it's highly inefficient because I'm repeatedly querying the same table.

My pseudocode:

- #for each barcode:
- #1. find all the transactions associated with that barcode
- #2. find all the barcodes associated with those transactions
- #3. final all the transactions associated with the barcodes in #2
- #4. repeat 2-3 until no further transactions are found
- #5. repeat 1-4 until no more barcodes, skipping previously seen barcodes

Do you have an alternative approach that's simpler/faster? Or any suggestions for optimisation?

Comment: You can do that with `networkx` but you have to collect the columns 'From' and 'To' from the spark cluster.

Comment: Thank you, I will check out networkx and report back :)

Comment: @Corralien Thank you! I didn't realise this was a graph problem.
I was able to represent my dataset as a DiGraph and enumerate all paths through the graph.

Comment: Glad to read you solved your problem :-) and thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

First, we create a column that shows the maximum value between *TransactionId_From* and *TransactionId_To*:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import greatest, col

df = df.withColumn(
   'TransactionGreatestID',
   greatest(col('TransactionId_From'), col('TransactionId_To')
                  )
```

Afterwards, you can use the dense_rank function to assign groups based on *TransactionGreatestID*:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank

window = Window.orderBy('TransactionGreatestID')
df = df.withColumn('GroupId', dense_rank().over(window))
```

In my experience, this shouldn't take too long to run. However, with the solution above we're assuming the data structure is good and every row for a given *GroupId* has the same value for *TransactionGreatestID*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I'm understanding correctly, I'm not sure this works in my example because group 2 would have 3 values for the greatest transaction ID (140, 149, 151), thus splitting this group into 3 groups.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df[['TransactionId_From', 'TransactionId_To']].fillna('nan'),
                            source='TransactionId_From', target='TransactionId_To',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)
G.remove_node('nan')

groups = {n: i for i, s in
          enumerate(nx.weakly_connected_components(G), start=1)
          for n in s}

df['GroupId'] = df['TransactionId_From'].map(groups)
```

Output:

```
   TransactionID  Amount  Barcode  TransactionId_From  TransactionId_To  GroupId
0            120    55.0    10001                 120             133.0        1
1            133    55.0    10001                 120             133.0        1
2            133    31.0    10008                 133               NaN        1
3            135    20.0    10022                 135             140.0        2
4             10    20.0    10022                 135             140.0        2
5            140     8.0    10056                 140             149.0        2
6            140    17.0    10067                 149               NaN        2
7            149     8.0    10056                 140             149.0        2
8            151     5.0    10056                 151               NaN        3
```